# Fastest collection type for adding and enumeration

Tags: c#

What is the fastest collection type when I don't care about duplicates, order etc. when I just want to add a specific type of object to it and then go through the collection with a for loop. I don't know how many items will be added.

I'm currently using a List(Of) as an array requires me to know the size which I don't know. But it's a bottleneck when the collection grows to a size of million of objects. What can be faster/better than a List(Of) in?

I've read some similar questions before. But I might be wrong but I felt like a hashset would be the wrong purpose since the idea of a set is not what I am going to do with it. An array like I said requires me to know the size before adding items. A dictionary is wrong purpose.

Comment: What exactly is a bottleneck? Iterating over a million-object list or adding more items to it?

Comment: Also do you mean "adding" as in "appending to the end" or "inserting anywhere in the collection"?

Comment: OR do you mean adding as in looping over the enumeration and adding its contents?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe List is such a bottleneck, here is the test program:

```
for (int max = 10000; max <= 10000000; max *= 10)
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            LinkedList<string> linkedlist = new LinkedList<string>();
            Queue<string> queue = new Queue<string>();
            HashSet<string> hashset = new HashSet<string>();
            string[] array = new string[max];

            Random rand = new Random();
            string value;

            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
            for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
                list.Add(rand.Next().ToString());
            for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
                value = list[i];
            DateTime dtlist = DateTime.Now;

            for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
                linkedlist.AddLast(rand.Next().ToString());
            var head=linkedlist.First;
            for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
            {
                value = head.Value;
                head = head.Next;
            }
            DateTime dtlinkedlist = DateTime.Now;

            for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
                queue.Enqueue(rand.Next().ToString());
            for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
                value = queue.Dequeue();
            DateTime dtqueue = DateTime.Now;

            for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
                hashset.Add(rand.Next().ToString());
            var ihash=hashset.GetEnumerator();
            for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
            {
                value = ihash.Current;
                ihash.MoveNext();
            }
            DateTime dthashset = DateTime.Now;

            for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
                array[i] = rand.Next().ToString();
            for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
                value = array[i];
            DateTime dtarray = DateTime.Now;


            Console.WriteLine("List " + list.Count + ": " + new TimeSpan(dtlist.Ticks - start.Ticks).TotalSeconds);
            Console.WriteLine("LinkedList " + linkedlist.Count + ": " + new TimeSpan(dtlinkedlist.Ticks - dtlist.Ticks).TotalSeconds);
            Console.WriteLine("Queue " + queue.Count + ": " + new TimeSpan(dtqueue.Ticks - dtlinkedlist.Ticks).TotalSeconds);
            Console.WriteLine("HashSet " + hashset.Count + ": " + new TimeSpan(dthashset.Ticks - dtqueue.Ticks).TotalSeconds);
            Console.WriteLine("Array " + array.Length + ": " + new TimeSpan(dtarray.Ticks - dthashset.Ticks).TotalSeconds);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

And this is the output on my PC:

```
List 10000: 0,0070058
LinkedList 10000: 0,0010009
Queue 0: 0,0020004
HashSet 10000: 0,0019973
Array 10000: 0,0040013

List 100000: 0,0139995
LinkedList 100000: 0,0270084
Queue 0: 0,0239972
HashSet 99992: 0,0320128
Array 100000: 0,0229999

List 1000000: 0,225034
LinkedList 1000000: 0,2970565
Queue 0: 0,2606011
HashSet 999767: 0,4960486
Array 1000000: 0,2189983

List 10000000: 2,3172126
LinkedList 10000000: 3,4592683
Queue 0: 3,1272267
HashSet 9976601: 6,2188591
Array 10000000: 2,3435249
```

Comment: You really should be using the Stopwatch class in the System.Diagnostics namespace for this kind of benchmarking.